# What are these open ports on my XWRT-based Netgear R7000 router?

Tags: networking, router, port

I recently flashed [XWRT-Vortex](http://xvtx.ru/xwrt/) on my Netgear R7000 router. Doing a local LAN port scan after the flash, I get the following:

```
$ nmap -p1-65535 192.168.1.1

Starting Nmap 7.40 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-05-30 06:20 PDT
Nmap scan report for R7000-A812 (192.168.1.1)
Host is up (0.010s latency).
Not shown: 65526 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
53/tcp    open  domain
80/tcp    open  http
515/tcp   open  printer
3394/tcp  open  d2k-tapestry2
3838/tcp  open  sos
5473/tcp  open  apsolab-tags
9100/tcp  open  jetdirect
9998/tcp  open  distinct32
18017/tcp open  unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 4.29 seconds
```

A few of these ports are obvious. Port 53 is for DNS. Port 80 is for the web interface. Ports 515 and 9100 are for printing.

What are these other ports that are open?

Comment: 80 is for the web interface, To find out what the others do you could try accressing them in a browser by opening e.g. `http://192.168.1.1:3394`

Answer (score 0):

IANA (The global coordination of the DNS Root, IP addressing, and other Internet protocol resources is performed as the Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA) functions.) has a complete list of all known ports and services being run on them.

Link to the port list:
https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml

Normally there's a link connected with the port with contact info and from that you can get the company URL, for instance, port 3394 is d2k-tapestry2 and the contact info mail refers to: http://d2k.com/

You can search the port numbers at the top to make it easier.